# How to wait while receiving a value from Useselector?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, dispatch

I am implementing a simple MyPage. When Mypage.tsx is first rendered, Redux saves user information as useEffect. However, when I try to get data with UseSelector from right below, it says that the value cannot be found.

Perhaps it is because the data is processed immediately while receiving the value. Is there a way to solve this?

> Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'myPostList' of null

**Part of error : const MyPost = userData.myPostList.map( .....**

```
import { GetUserInfo } from "../modules/action-creator";
import { RootState } from "../modules/Store";
import "../styles/mypage.scss";



function Mypage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    dispatch(GetUserInfo())
  }, [])
  

  const userData = useSelector((state : RootState) => state.User.userData)
  

  const MyPost = userData.myPostList.map(
    (item:any, index:number) => {
      return(
        <tbody id = {"body" + index} key = {item.id}>
          <tr>
            <td id = "title">{item.postName}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id = "content">{item.content}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      )
    }
  )
    
  return (
        <div className="mypost">
          <div className="post_info">
            전체글 0개
            <button>글쓰기</button>
          </div>
          <table className="post_detail">{MyPost == null ? "표시할 정보가 없습니다." : MyPost}</table>
        </div>
  )
}
```

As explained below, it seems that the data was processed before receiving all the values. Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check `userData` to make sure it has value before using it. You should use `optional chaining` in this case

```
const MyPost = userData?.myPostList?.map(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer didn't help you, it might be useful debuging how you are storing this values in reducer. I also suggest debuging the Actions (on saga/thunk).

This could happen due to wrong prop name selections, or even a bad request, if you are using midlewares.

Comment: Could you give me more details?